# How to play radio in background of WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, progressive-web-apps, playback, internet-radio

I have embedded an online radio station from Radio.net, my brief is to develop a Web-App so I am building this on a WordPress website environment using the embed widget.

Radio.net has provided this embed code:

```js
<script> (function(d, s) {
    if (!window.rel) {
        s = d.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.async = true;
        s.id = "radio-de-embedded";
        s.src = "//www.radio.net/inc/microsite/js/full.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
        window.rel = true;
    }
}(document)); < /script><div class="ng-app-embedded"><div ui-view class="microsite embedded-radio-player" data-playerwidth="340px" data-playertype="web_embedded" data-playstation="keithngesi" data-autoplay="true" data-apikey="abcdef..."></div>
```

1. How can I achieve an instance where the radio play keeps playing whilst the website or Web-App is still active or online?
2. The Radio player keeps playing when a user switches pages?

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a [Single page application](https://flaviocopes.com/single-page-application/)

Here is a [Jump start](https://www.sitepoint.com/single-page-app-without-framework/)